# Voltage value after generators in the power grid

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, generator, power-grid

What is the value of the voltage before the step-up transformers and right after the generators in the power grid?

I mean the generators connected to the high voltage grid through step-up transformers. What type of power plants are they? I know that voltages change country by country, but I want to know the average value

Comment: You won't find an average value. You'll find values for specific ratings of generator : a 50MW one will likely run at lower voltage than a 660MW or 1000 MW one. Pick a few representative generators and start reading about them.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you very much Brian!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend not only on country but also by site, as larger power generators tend to have higher voltages. For an example, [Siemens provide a catalogue](https://www.siemens-energy.com/global/en/offerings/power-generation/generators/sgen-3000w.html):

> Up to 27 kV

Comment: Very thanks! I have seen the catalog and I found only steam generators and combined-cycle generators. So these are the only two types of generators connected to the HV grid?

Comment: More likely they are the only ones in that catalogue. Plenty of other types connect to the grid.